# Using Antizer over AntDesign, how can we access things like Card.Meta?

Tags: clojurescript, antd

How to translate examples like this from antd docs to the antizer clojurescript world? See code from https://ant.design/components/card/

  `<Card
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    cover={<img alt="example" src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/JiqGstEfoWAOHiTxclqi.png" />}
    actions={[<Icon type="setting" />, <Icon type="edit" />, <Icon type="ellipsis" />]}
  >
    <Meta
      avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />}
      title="Card title"
      description="This is the description"
    />`

Answer (score 0):

The translated reagent code should be like:

```
[card {:style   {:width 300}
       :cover   (as-element
                  [img {:src "https://gw.alipayo..."
                        :alt "example"}])
       :actions (map as-element
                     [[icon {:type "setting"}]
                      [icon {:type "edit"}]
                      [icon {:type "ellipsis"}]])}
 [meta {:avatar      (as-element
                       [avatar {:src "https://zos.alipayobj..."}])
        :title       "Card title"
        :description "This is the description"}]]
```

[as-element](http://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/reagent.core.html#var-as-element) is used to convert reagent element to plain react element